# Create "Yesterday's Value" variable for multiple time series

Tags: r, performance, time-series

I am working on a project in R, and I am a bit stuck. I have four time series in this format:

```
x <- data.frame(Id = rep(c(1,2,3,4),2), 
                Date = c(rep("1980-01-01",4), rep("1980-01-02",4)),
                Freq = c(2,3,1,2,4,5,2,3))

ID        Date        Freq
1   1980 - 01 - 01      2
2   1980 - 01 - 01      3
3   1980 - 01 - 01      1
4   1980 - 01 - 01      2
1   1980 - 01 - 02      4
2   1980 - 01 - 02      5  
3   1980 - 01 - 02      2
4   1980 - 01 - 02      3
```

My goal is to make a new variable that is simply yesterday's freq value for that group.

```
ID        Date        Freq   YestFreq
1   1980 - 01 - 01      2       NA
2   1980 - 01 - 01      3       NA
3   1980 - 01 - 01      1       NA
4   1980 - 01 - 01      2       NA 
1   1980 - 01 - 02      4       2
2   1980 - 01 - 02      5       3
3   1980 - 01 - 02      2       1
4   1980 - 01 - 02      3       2
```

My attempted solution is:

```
x$DateID = paste(x$ID, x$Date)
x$yesterday = as.Date(x$Date) - 1
x$YesterdayDateID = paste(x$ID, x$yesterday)

result = numeric(nrow(x))
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  answer = x$Freq[which(x$DateID == x$yesterdayDateID[i])]
  if(length(answer) != 0){result[i] = answer} else{result[i] = NA}
}
x = cbind(x, result)
```

My actual data set has  ~ 600000 rows, (~300 Id and ~ 2000 unique dates) so my above solution takes a solid 2 hours to run. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MattParker Are you working on this with the OP? Otherwise, it's kind of weird for you to make an edit claiming that more columns are involved than the single one displayed.

Comment: @Frank There are four series/groups in the sample data - four unique values in `Id` - which is what separates this question from the many prior questions on lagging. I was just trying to emphasize that aspect of it to keep the question from being marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @MattParker Okay, fair enough. I'm pretty sure "lag by grouping variable" has also been asked before, too, though. If anything, this question is different because it refers to "yesterday" as opposed to "the day immediately prior in the data"... doesn't matter for the example given, but that was the idea behind Pierre's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  arrange(as.Date(Date), Id) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(YestFreq = lag(Freq))
#    Id       Date  Freq YestFreq
#  (dbl)     (fctr) (dbl)    (dbl)
#1     1 1980-01-01     2       NA
#2     2 1980-01-01     3       NA
#3     3 1980-01-01     1       NA
#4     4 1980-01-01     2       NA
#5     1 1980-01-02     4        2
#6     2 1980-01-02     5        3
#7     3 1980-01-02     2        1
#8     4 1980-01-02     3        2
```

Comment: One complication: The OP chose to define `yesterday = as.Date(x$Date) - 1`, so if their data has gaps (so yesterday is sometimes not in the data set), there would be trouble using `lag` (unless those gaps were filled in first).

Comment: With a fresh session, it worked. I must have had another package masking something.

Comment: @Frank Suppose if the 6th date is `1980-01-24`, what should be the corresponding 'YestFreq'.   Is it NA?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. The preliminary step of expanding the data to fill in gaps would be sufficient if the OP had that problem (I think). Anyway, just thought I'd bring it up.

Comment: @Frank Please post your idea as a separate answer.  I am a bit tired to work on it.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't actually thought it through either :)

Comment: @Frank Anyway, feeling sleepy, see you tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

To take into account the possible yesterday gaps. I use `match` to identify the previous day. From that index then subset the target column by Id:

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, Date := as.IDate(Date)][
, YestFreq := Freq[match(Date-1L, Date)], by=Id][]
#   Id       Date Freq YestFreq
# 1:  1 1980-01-01    2       NA
# 2:  2 1980-01-01    3       NA
# 3:  3 1980-01-01    1       NA
# 4:  4 1980-01-01    2       NA
# 5:  1 1980-01-02    4        2
# 6:  2 1980-01-02    5        3
# 7:  3 1980-01-02    2        1
# 8:  4 1980-01-02    3        2
```

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date)
x %>% group_by(Id) %>% mutate(YestFreq = Freq[match(Date - 1L, Date)])
#   Id       Date Freq YestFreq
# 1  1 1980-01-01    2       NA
# 2  2 1980-01-01    3       NA
# 3  3 1980-01-01    1       NA
# 4  4 1980-01-01    2       NA
# 5  1 1980-01-02    4        2
# 6  2 1980-01-02    5        3
# 7  3 1980-01-02    2        1
# 8  4 1980-01-02    3        2
```

Answer (score 2):

For a fast solution use the data.table package, sort the data and derive a column per group that uses the Freq value of the previous row:

```
library(data.table)

x <- data.frame(Id = rep(c(1,2,3,4),2), Date = c(rep("1980-01-01",4), rep("1980-01-02",4)), Freq = c(2,3,1,2,4,5,2,3))

# The real solution starts here (could even be done in one row):
y <- setDT(x)      # convert to data.table
setkey(y,Id,Date)  # "sort" the data
y[, .(Date, Freq, YestFreq=c(NA, Freq[1:(.N-1)])), by=.(Id)]
```

The output is (differently ordered -> by Id):

```
   Id       Date Freq YestFreq
1:  1 1980-01-01    2       NA
2:  1 1980-01-02    4        2
3:  2 1980-01-01    3       NA
4:  2 1980-01-02    5        3
5:  3 1980-01-01    1       NA
6:  3 1980-01-02    2        1
7:  4 1980-01-01    2       NA
8:  4 1980-01-02    3        2
```

**Edit 1:**

You could do it in one line (and sort the results as requested too):

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.frame(Id = rep(c(1,2,3,4),2), Date = c(rep("1980-01-01",4), rep("1980-01-02",4)), Freq = c(2,3,1,2,4,5,2,3))

setDT(x, key=c("Id", "Date"))[, YestFreq := c(NA, Freq[1:(.N-1)]), by=Id][order(Date, Id)]
```

Result:

```
   Id       Date Freq YestFreq
1:  1 1980-01-01    2       NA
2:  2 1980-01-01    3       NA
3:  3 1980-01-01    1       NA
4:  4 1980-01-01    2       NA
5:  1 1980-01-02    4        2
6:  2 1980-01-02    5        3
7:  3 1980-01-02    2        1
8:  4 1980-01-02    3        2
```